# Is it safe to bench press another person?

Tags: gym, injury-prevention, bench-press

My bench max is 225, and I am seriously considering benching my 150 Ib friend at the gym. He says I can do it if I want. Is this safe, and what is the worst outcome. What is the likely outcome?

Comment: If your buddy has any core strength, then you'll bench him. If not, you'll drop him on you. Either way you'll look pretty silly.

Answer (score 3):

#### Can You Bench Your Friend?

***Theoretically Yes***......but I think the biggest problem you'll face is your friend lying still like a barbell. Since ***humans instinctively fight for control when they're off balance***, it might be relatively hard for you to keep your friend in the air.

Another problem will be the ***"handle bars"***. What regions of your friend will you be holding?

#### Is It Safe?

I wouldn't consider it safe for the above reasoning. Because your friend might instinctively fight for control, the force exerted on you will be greater than just his physical weight alone. This might cause you to lose balance of him and presto......***you both crash.***

#### Likely Questions To Consider

- What parts of his body will you hold while lifting him and how stable will those be? *Unless you're planning on strapping him on a pole like a roasted pig, this might be a big problem.*
- Where is the starting position? Bench press stations usually have stands for the barbell before lifting. Where will you put your friend?
- Inherently dangerous stunts like this usually have spotters *(in case something goes wrong).* Do you have one?
- Last but not least......***why?***

#### In Summary

If you can provide solutions to the above questions, you should be able perform this activity. Unless it's for one of those wacky/goofy videos, I don't see the point though. ***I would, however, be curious about the result***  :).

Comment: Before Zod We tried this earlier this morning, the first two times he fell on me but the third time I lifted him. This is strange,because I can knock out about 9 or 10 reps with a 150 Ib barbell.

Comment: Well, the weight of a barbell is evenly distributed; human weight isn't :p Curious though, ***how did you hold your friend and where was the starting position?***

Comment: Before Zod He climbed onto me and I held his front and our other friend lifted him to the starting position